# Clonar select con sus item

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

he buscando mucho pero no encuentro respuesta: tengo un div con 3 select diferentes (cada uno con su id), nececisto que al presionar un boton estos se clonen con un nuevo id. me a resultado lo de clonar pero al hacer clic en el select creado no hace nada, es importante que tengan id diferentes ya que despues necesito tomar los valores para guardarlos en una base de datos.

De antemano muchas Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y como los clonaste?

Answer (score 0):

hola Jose quizá esto te sirva, se hace manejo del DOM y Bootstrap (lo puedes ver en las clases de las etiquetas.

En el botón debes poner una función tal que así:

```
onclick="asigSelect()"
```

En la función javascript puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
idSelect =0; //esta variable es la que te permite definir el identificador de cada selesct.

function asigSelect(){
    
    idSelect++;

    let divId = document.getElementById(id del div que creaste);

    let select = document.createElement("select"); 
    select.className = "form-control mt-2";
    select.placeholder = "Seleccione una opcion...";
    select.id = `select${idSelect}`; 
    
// acá puedes definir la cantidad de veces que deseas iterar, según la cantidad de veces que iteres, es la cantidad de opciones que crearás.

    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = `${i}`;
        option.text = `Opcion ${i}`;

        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    divId.appendChild(select);
}
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer], en especial la sección _contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un servicio para proveer código: aguarda a que OP (autor de la pregunta) muestre un [repro] de lo que ha intentado hasta el momento.